# Rails Thinking Sphinx All Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm not sure if accomplishing problem is impossible, so help me out. If running a search like this

```
@things = Thing.search params[:search]
```

for 'jack' returns all results with relevance 'jack'. and 'sushi' returns all results with relevance 'sushi'. But if i type 'jack sushi' i get only results with both relevance 'jack' and 'sushi'. What if i want all results with either relevance but most relevance higher in my results. (so i if i typed in 'jack sushi' then if something relates to 'jack' but not 'sushi' i still get it as a result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a different `match_mode`.  You could use `:any` which matches any of the words you type in, or `:boolean` and search for "jack or sushi".

Example

```
@things = Thing.search params[:search], :match_mode => :any
```

Hope this helps.